# Reducing memory usage when storing all subsequences of a set of sequences

Tags: common-lisp

I have a set of input sequences (represented as lists), for each of which I'm generating a set of all of its subsequences (also lists).  These subsequences are stored as keys in an EQUAL hash-table, and never garbage collected or modified (the associated values, however, are modified).

My problem is that the method I'm currently using to accomplish this uses far more heap space than I'd like.

To be clear about what I'm talking about, suppose we have a sequence:

```
#1=(A B C D)
```

The subsequences are:

```
#2=()
#3=(A)
#4=(A B)
#5=(A B C)
#6=(A B C D)
#7=(B)
#8=(B C)
#9=(B C D)
#10=(C)
#11=(C D)
#12=(D)
```

The following code, which I admit isn't very good, produces this set (except the empty subsequence which I don't actually care about):

```
(defun subseqs-of-length (length sequence)
  (if (< (length sequence) length)
      nil
      (loop for start from 0 to (- (length sequence) length)
           collect (subseq sequence start (+ start length)))))

(defun subseqs-of-length-< (length sequence)
  (loop for len from 1 to (1- length)
     append (subseqs-of-length len sequence)))

(defun all-subseqs (sequence)
    (subseqs-of-length-< (1+ (length sequence)) sequence))
```

As you can probably imagine, with a lot of input sequences, this uses up a huge amount of heap.

The most obvious way I can think of to save memory is to share a bunch of list structure; for instance, you can build list 11 by `(cons 'c '#12#)`, list 9 by `(cons 'b '#11#)`, list 8 by `(cons 'b '#10#` and so forth.  It would be even better if the output of multiple calls to `all-subseqs` could share structure.  But I can't think of an elegant way to write this.

My question is two-fold:

1. Is there an elegant way to write `all-subseqs` so that its results will share structure that way?
2. It occurred to me that it might be easier to generate the subsequences naïvely and write a function to compress the results and run it periodically.  Isn't this a silly idea?
3. Is there an even more memory efficient way to store these subsequences and access/update the values associated with them?  Perhaps something using arrays, or a different data structure instead of a hash-table?

Comment: Why do you want to store subsequences? Your answer may help us with a solution.

Comment: Statistics.  For each subsequence I'm storing the number of times it's followed by each symbol, and the number of times it's last.  The main question I'm looking to answer is "given (a b c), what's likely to come next?".  I'm also interested in which subsequences are common, and in the future I may want to derive facts like "(a b) is common, and (b c) is common, but (a b c) never occurs."

Comment: Im pretty sure you really want a count tree here.

Comment: Perhaps... what's a count tree?

Comment: OK, i'll go ahead and make a full answer

Answer (score 2):

What is the minimal amount of information needed to reconstruct a subsequence?

How about the sequence, a start index, and end index. Store the start/end indexes in a two-dimensional hash table (a hash table of hash tables), or a 2-d array. Then write functions to do work on that data structure (reconstruct the subsequence given the sequence, a start index, and end index, etc).

Another idea: If you really want to store the subsequences in the data structure, you could use an N-dimensional hash table (a hash table of hash tables of hash tables ...), where N is the length of the sequence. Instead of a linked list of elements, you get a linked tree of hash tables. There is a special key in each hash table, storing the actual value of the keyed sequence all the way up to that point (that is, if this keyed sequence actually has a value). And other links in each hash table point to branches further down the tree.

And if each element in the list is a symbol, then an 'a in one list will be eq (share same mem location) as an 'a in another list. Which I think means you can get O(N) storage growth + whatever incremental growth occurs by adding links to the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

In general you would have to store so many sequences that you'll quickly fill memory. Another datastructure that is more suitable to store frequency information of sequences is a count/frequency tree.

A count tree is just a regular tree augmented with frequency information in each node. Each node in the tree can have several children, infact all characters in your alphabet. Allocating for all can be pretty wasteful so just use a simple linked-list as a key-value, and let the next character in the sequence be the key, with the node representing that being value. In this scheme, the root node represent the empty sequence. This of course lets you calculate P(C | A,B) by looking up the path A,B,C in the tree and dividing the frequency of A,B,C by the freq. of A.B to get the basic MLE estimate.

```
(defstruct lm-tree-node
  (total 0)
  (children (make-lash)))

(defun add-sequence (seq lm-root &optional (count 1))
  (let ((children (lm-tree-node-children lm-root)))
    (incf (lm-tree-node-total lm-root) count)
    (let ((child
           (get-or-add-lash (first seq) children (make-lm-tree-node))))
      (if (rest seq)
          (add-sequence (rest seq) child count)
        (incf (lm-tree-node-total child) count)))))
```

To put your data in the tree just take all your sequences, start at the root and add 1 to the frequency of all nodes as you walk your sequences.  The above code is from a project where I made a language model for a Hidden Markov Model decoder. It's on github if some wan tto take a look.  A "lash"-table is just a common key-value linked list that can transform itself into a hash-table if needed. Since the count tree can have *really many* nodes, it's important that they have a small memory footprint, and a hash-table in every node is out of the question. Typically only the top nodes in the count-tree will have many (hundred or so) children, so it is beneficial if these can use a hash-table.

If you want all sequences in an n-gram manner for language modeling you have to go to some extra hoops; splitting up every token read into ordered n-grams but *also* making sure to add the n-1 gram and the n-2 gram and so on.

```
(defun sentence-to-n-grams (sentence n lm-root)
  (let ((buffer (make-fast-queue :size n :buffer (make-array n))))
  (loop
      for word fixnum in sentence
      for seq = (fast-queue-to-list (fast-enqueue buffer word))
      when (>= (length seq) n)
      do (add-sequence seq lm-root)
      finally (loop
                  for x on (rest seq)
                  do (add-sequence x lm-root)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the first question:

```
(defun all-subseqs (list)
  (loop :for sublist := list :then (butlast sublist)
        :while sublist
        :nconc (maplist #'identity sublist)))
```

This lets all subsequences that have the same tail share structure.

For the application you outline, there *must* be a better data structure.  The count trees shown by Johan look promising.